# Swipe effect sensibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i trying to use the swipe effect for a mobile app. i have tested and works to change page. but its very sensitive. lot of times i want only to scroll and he change the page.

it is possible to fixed the sensibility on touchscreen on this event?

here is my code:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile, you need to set new values for the horizontal and vertical drag distance `horizontalDistanceThreshold` and `verticalDistanceThreshold`.

Note that you need to bind the change to `mobileinit` event and the code should be placed into `<head>` after loading jQuery js file and before loading jQuery-Mobile js.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
 $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = '100'; // default 30px
 $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = '150'; // default 75px
});
</script>

<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

> **Reference: [Swipe event - jQuery Mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)**

Answer (score 2):

adjust the swipe thresholds like this

```
$.swipe.defaults.threshold.x = '30'; //for horizontal swiping sensitivity
$.swipe.defaults.threshold.y = '10'; //for vertical swiping sensitivity
```

just add these codes to change the global sensitivity of the swipes of your application and do your usual codes after putting the code above

to directly change the sensitivity on a certain element you can do something like this

```
$('[data-role="page"]').swipe({ threshold: {x: 30, y: 20},
swipeLeft: function() { alert('swiped left') },
swipeRight: function() { alert('swiped right') }});
```

Comment: ok.. can you tell me in which line i have to insert? thx for the post

Comment: then increase the threshold as needed