# jQuery Mobile panel- adding swipe only at right side

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I have created web page for toch device using Bootsrap and jQuery mobile.

Page contain one carousal in middle of page which slide left/right as per swipe done by user.
Page contain [Jquery Mobile panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-swipe-open/#demo-intro&ui-state=dialog) which open only if user swipe right.

My problem is if user swipe right on carousal, Panel opens automatically. I want when user swipe  right at edge of right side(around 75px) then only Panel must open.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Bxxloder and JQM</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
        <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
        <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--#########################JQM#########################-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="demo-page" data-url="demo-page">
        <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">
            <p>Left reveal panel.</p>
            <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-theme="b">
            <p>Right push panel.</p>
            <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Close</a>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    <!--#########################//JQM#########################-->
    <!--#########################Bx slider#########################-->
    <section class="row col-lg-10" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="image/b.png" title="Funky roots" /></li>
      <li><img src="image/b.png" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
      <li><img src="image/b.png" title="Happy trees" /></li>
    </ul>
    </section>              
    <!--######################### End Swipe Carousel ##############################-->
    </div>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider(
    {
        mode: 'horizontal',
        captions: true,
        auto: true,
        touchEnabled: true,
        oneToOneTouch: true,
        /* controls: false,*/
        pager: false,
        speed: 200
    });
});
    </script>
    <script>
$(document).on("pagecreate", function()
{    
    $(document).on("swipe", function(e)
    {         
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        //if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" )
        if($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open" && !$(e.target).hasClass("bxslider"))
        {            
            if(e.type === "swipe")
            {                
                $("#right-panel").panel("open");            
            }
            else if(e.type === "swipe")
            {                
                $("#left-panel").panel("open");            
            }        
        }    
    });
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add another condition in `if` statement `if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" && !e.target.hasClass("bxslider"))`

Comment: correction: `!$(e.target).hasClass("bxslider")` should be a jQuery object.

Comment: @Omar:Code updated as per comment, Now whole panel is not working.

Comment: ok `console.log(e.target)`, check which item receives the swipe.

Comment: @Omar:My panel is not working at all in any case in FF. Where to write console.log.

Comment: after `swipe` function.

Comment: its give 'ReferenceError: e is not defined'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65852/discussion-between-mike-phils-and-omar).

Comment: $( document ).on( "swipe", function( e ), e is defined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mikephils/f9Lk6eag/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first `if` statement add another condition that the element which received the `swipe` isn't wrapped by slider.

```
$(document).on("swipe", function (e) {
  if ($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open" &&  $(e.target).closest(".bxslider").length === 0) {
    /* code */
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c5rmpgpv/)**

Comment: It work fine thanks lot!!!,but my panel is not coming at one touch in touch device, can we add some touch effect radius at right edges.

Comment: @MikePhils you're welcome :) the panel isn't opening on swipe? can you explain the situation?

Comment: panel work fine is PC, but on mobile when i swipe right sometime it come sometime it don't. can we add some swipe effect area near right edges.

Comment: @MikePhils I just tested the code in ipad, it's working as expected. You can increase/decrease swipe distance before swipe is triggered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16523579/1771795

Comment: used this and it work $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = (screen.availWidth) / 60; // (default: 30) (pixels) – Swipe horizontal displacement must be less than this.

Comment: $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = (screen.availWidth) / 100; //changed 100 from 60, it is working.But not understood about (screen.availWidth) / 100; , could u please guide it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196139/jquery-code-which-check-the-internet-network-is-available-or-not-mobile-pc-tabl any idea about this.