# Jquery Code which check the internet/network is available or not (mobile/PC/Tablet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Web page Jquery Code which check the internet/network is there or not(mobile/PC/Tablet).Itscheck system internet/network. It's static page.

Page contain button(buttons created with anchor tag)

**If connection is on then button is get enable.**

**If connection is off then button is disable**

Like this:- http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/navigator.onLine.html

Comment: How precisely do you expect the user to be viewing your web page without an Internet connection?

Comment: @duskwuff: just need to test for local purpose, after certain interval should check, it can be ajax call also,but anchor button must change

Comment: @duskwuff: let say 1000ms